# How can I allow camera for a Google Apps Script Web App deployed in Kiosk Mode on a Chromebook?

Tags: google-apps-script, web-applications, kiosk-mode, chromebook

My Google Apps Script Web App uses the web camera to enable users to take a photo, but when I deploy it on a Chromebook in Kiosk Mode (using Chrome Sign Builder) then the camera is not allowed and there doesn't seem to be a way to allow the camera.  Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 0):

#### This was the form I used for a webapp that allowed me to take images of the receipt

The input type file produced a dialog on my iphone that allowed me to take and image.

```
<form id="myForm">
    <br /><input type="date" name="date" id="dt"/>
    <br /><input type="number" name="amount" placeholder="Amount" id="amt" />
    <br /><input type="text" name="vendor" placeholder="Vendor" id="vndr"/>
    <br /><textarea name="notes" cols="40" rows="2" placeholder="NOTES" 
id="notes"></textarea>
    <br/>Receipt Image
    <br /><input type="file" name="receipt" id="img" />
    <br /><input type="button" value="Submit" 
onclick="fileUploadJs(this.parentNode)" />
  </form>
```

Comment: Thanks Cooper, but I believe that the device and user this is running for would still need to give permission for the use of the camera.  My issue is more that I can't find a way of giving permission for the camera when deploying a Web App (using the camera) to a Chromebook using Kiosk mode (via Chrome Sign Builder).